# when i run this code it give error unexpected else please suggest mi how to write it

Tags: php

when i run this code it give error unexpected else please suggest mi   how to write it i am confused with open and close bracket

```
     <?php
     } 

     for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) 
     {

    //if ($cur_page == $i)
    if($i != $page)?>

     <a href="javascript:callonce_search( <?php echo $i?>,'<?php echo        $txt?>')"> $i </a>



  <?php 
    else
      echo " <a class='paginationcurrnt'><b> $i</b>";
     }


    // TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
   if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) 
    {
    $nex = $cur_page + 1; ?>
```

Comment: The code snippet as is appears to be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are your friend when you want to explicitly define code blocks:

```
if($i != $page) { ?>
    <a href="javascript:callonce_search( <?php echo $i?>,'<?php echo        $txt?>')"> $i </a>
<?php 
} else {
    echo " <a class='paginationcurrnt'><b> $i</b>";
}
```

Sometimes, in the case of single-line code blocks, you can get away with not using them.  But when mixing code with markup like this, the concept of "a line of code" becomes pretty effectively blurred.  In that case, always explicitly use curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

This is very poorly written code. The syntax error is because your `else` comes out of nowhere. This is the format for `if/else` statements:

```
if(condition){
    //if condition is true
} else {
    //if condition is false
}
```

This is yours:

```
if(condition)
else
}
```

So change the `if/else` to:

```
if($i != $page) { ?>
    <a href="javascript:callonce_search( <?php echo $i?>,'<?php echo $txt ?>')"> $i </a>
<?php } else {
    echo " <a class='paginationcurrnt'><b> $i</b>";
}
```